Doubts with Tkinter Designer (Problem with URL)
I would like to know if you can give me some help because I'm having problems generating the code in Tkinter Designer, when I press the "Generate" button the message appears: "Please enter a valid file URL." Even though I put the right figma link.
Figma Link: https://www.figma.com/design/WiMfqKoch17dlyb5i0NiWM/Trabalho?node-id=0-1&t=7jUprtPCdYYI0doV-0
Error
I'm trying to generate this interface made in Figma for Tkinter Designer, but when I access the Tkinter Designer screen and generate the code I receive this image error message

replace match = re.search(r'https://www.figma.com/design/([0-9A-Za-z_-]+)/', URL.strip())

inside tkinter gui.py file, it will work.
